# NameError with extend_path using Bazel

Tags: python, bazel, init, bazel-rules, bazel-python

I am trying to make a python program using bazel. When running the following snippet of code:

```
__path__ = __import__('pkgutil').extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

I am given the following error:

`NameError: name '__path__' is not defined`

Comment: Your call to `.extend_path()` passes `__path__` as an argument. What do you expect `__path__` to contain?

Comment: its acutally coming from a bazel generated file. So I dont know what path its expecting

Comment: Im trying to install tackle-box and use its cli to compile a yaml file

Comment: Can you share more details on the above error. Like which python, bazel versions are you using ? Is it in windows or any other OS ?